# Is this black locust?

Tags: species-identification, botany

This grows in Modiin, Israel. The leaves look like black locust (*Pseudoacacia robinia*) to me, but the branches are very knobby. Can anyone identify it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Doesn't look like locust to me, but that's just a guess.  If it's a locust, the stems will probably have thorns on them.  Also, if mature enought it will have clusters of cream colored (or pink in one variety), fragrant, pea-shaped flowers in another month or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the photos are less than ideal, and I can't see any flowers or fruit, I can clearly see that the leaves are "evenly pinnate" and rounded distally (not pointed). The wood structure also looks bumpy.  Given Israel as the neighborhood, it is likely to be a carob tree (*Ceratonia siliqua*) which is native to the Mediterranean region.  This tree is sometimes mistakenly called a "locust" tree.  See Links below.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceratonia_siliqua

http://tree-species.blogspot.com/2008/04/carob-tree-ceratonia-siliqua.html